# MyClass is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am building a custom framework in swift.I have builded the framework for all the architecture. I am using Debug-Universal build in my sample app. Now when I run the app, It works fine in the simulator but while running on the device, I am getting the error **Breeze is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class**[image]

When I am using Release-Universal it is giving **No such Module BreezeSDK**

[image]

Comment: see if the breezeSDK added as framework for target "ExperimentFramework2"?

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps after creating the universal binaries:

Before `lipo`, you are building `.framework` packages for the individual architectures.

For each package:

1. Traverse to  `abc.framework/Modules/abc`
2. Copy files `.swiftdoc`
3. Go into `universal abc`
4. Traverse to  `abc.framework/Modules/abc`
5. Paste the files you copied in step 2

Repeat these steps for all architectures.

Finally your universal framework package path `abc.framework/Modules/abc.swiftmodule/` should contain
those files:

- arm.swiftdoc
- arm.swiftmodule
- arm64.swiftdoc
- arm64.swiftmodule
- i386.swiftdoc
- i386.swiftmodule
- x86_64.swiftdoc
- x86_64.swiftmodule

The Swift compiler needs swiftmodule map files for each architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

1. Download Bareeze SDK.
2. Drag and add Breeze.xcodeproj to your project.
3. Next, select your application project in the Project Navigator (blue project icon) to navigate to the target configuration window and select the application target under the "Targets" heading in the sidebar.
4. In the tab bar at the top of that window, open the "General" panel.
5. Click on the + button under the "Embedded Binaries" section.
6. Select the top Breeze.framework

Hope this might solve the issue.

Comment: I have included it in Build Phases->Link Binary

Comment: Deployment target in Breeze SDK and in your project is same?

Comment: Yes deployment target is same in both. 9.0

Comment: Delete Breeze SDK and add again to project.

Comment: I repeated it many times. Even cleaned the trash. Did quit the xcode and restarted again.